# $_SESSION variable works on localhost and fails in live

Tags: php

I'm using $_session to print the user name on the top of the index page when user is connected. The script works fine on localhost but fails in live.

On my index page i start by `<?php session_start(); ?>`. and then i check if session variable is available with `if(isset($_SESSION["uid"]))`.

The javascrip work jjust fine and give back statut 202. But seems the session variable is lost.

On the login process I have defined two $_SESSION like so:

```
$_SESSION["uid"] = $row["vendors_id"];
$_SESSION["name"] = $row["vendors_name"];
```

Now on my index page in the top I start by:

```
<?php
session_start();
require "db.php";

?>
```

And then I use the script below to print user name if he's connected to his account. The problem is that it’s working on the localhost only. On the live the user name isn’t displayed when I try to login.

```
        <?php     
            if(isset($_SESSION["uid"])){
                    echo "
                        <div class='dropdown'>
                        
                        <a class='' data-toggle='dropdown'>$_SESSION[name] <i class='icon-sort-down' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> 
                        <div class='dropdown-content'>
                            <a href='edit_profile.php'>Profile</a>
                            <a href='mesannonces.php'>Mes annonces</a>
                            <a href='annonce_save.php'>Ma liste de sauvgarde</a>
                            <a href='logout.php'>Déconexion</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                            
                        "; 
                    }
                else {
                    echo "
                    <a href='#login' data-toggle='modal' style='padding-right:0;vertical-align: sub;'>

                    <svg style='vertical-align: text-bottom;' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-person-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>
                    <path d='M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z'/>
                    <path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z'/>
                    </svg>
                    Connexion
                    </a>
            
                        ";
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: _....The javascrip work jjust fine and give back statut 202...._ What javascript?

Comment: There is no `$_session`, it's `$_SESSION`. What doesn't work? Can you post a more complete version of your code?

Comment: Where are you writing to the session?

Comment: I just edited my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

As i saw here you have syntax error.

```
<a class='' data-toggle='dropdown'>$_SESSION[name] <i class='icon-sort-......
```

Now the problem is you just echoing full sentence.so you must do concatenation here. And you need to write this $_SESSION["name"] instade of $_SESSION[name] and then use the following code.

```
echo "<div class='dropdown'>
                    
                    <a class='' data-toggle='dropdown'>".$_SESSION["name"]."<i class='icon-sort-down' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> 
                    <div class='dropdown-content'>
                        <a href='edit_profile.php'>Profile</a>
                        <a href='mesannonces.php'>Mes annonces</a>
                        <a href='annonce_save.php'>Ma liste de sauvgarde</a>
                        <a href='logout.php'>Déconexion</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>";
```

So this can help you if your problem persists then let me know in comments.

Comment: unfortunately this correction doesn't solve the issue. The user name isn't displayed. I don't understand why on localhost this correction doesn't matter even without it the name is displayed. thanks

Comment: This can be due to server problem

Comment: You can use this commands before the session_start command 
```$sessdir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/session_dir';
ini_set('session.save_path', $sessdir);```

Comment: If this not works please let me know and see that you have permission to write in your /tmp/ folder in server

Comment: Finally, i have activated the display error on my cpanel. it was about a space before the <?php tag which cause the issue. Thank you @Somen Das